# How do I make sure a String is always followed by a Character in regular expression?

Tags: regex

Here are a few examples which are valid in my scenario:

```
apple  
apple,banana  
apple,banana,mango
```

But these are invalid:

```
apple,  
,apple  
apple,banana,
```

This is the regular expression that I have:

`(apple|banana|mango)(,(apple|banana|mango))*`

I can see that the problem is with `(,(apple|banana|mango))*` since it means any number of occurrences of `,` and one of apple, banana and mango. I need to make sure that if there is a comma, it is followed by a fruit name.

I am not trying to validate duplicate fruit names here i.e. `apple,apple,banana,apple` is valid.

So how can I do this ?

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: I can't see any problem with `(,(apple|banana|mango))*` that you are talking about - it doesn't match `","` nor `",,banana"` - it only matches 1 comma followed by 1 of the words.

Comment: @Aprillion my bad. that part is fine.

Comment: This looks strangely like a CSV issue. Is it? Just split on `,`, look for empty fields.

Comment: @sln I don't have the option to get the string directly. It's part of a configuration file. A framework will parse the string according to the regular expression provided, and give the values in an array.

Comment: @ShubhamAggarwal - `^[^,]+(?:,[^,]+)*$` validate's the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to ensure that there are no leading or trailing characters around your match, you need to use start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors, like this:

```
^(apple|banana|mango)(,(apple|banana|mango))*$
```

Or for simplicity, you can use a negative lookbehind (`(?<!…)`) if your chosen platform supports it:

```
^((^|(?<!^),)(apple|banana|mango))+$
```

Or alternatively a negative lookahead (`(?!…)`):

```
^((apple|banana|mango)(,(?!$)|$))+$
```

And since you brought it up, *if* you want to ensure that your pattern does not match strings that have duplicate fruit names, you can use a negative lookahead and a backreference (`\n`), like this:

```
^(((?<!^),)?(apple|banana|mango)(?!.*\3))+$
```

This will match `apple,banana` but not `apple,banana,apple`.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex platform supports lookarounds then you can use this regex:

```
(?<!^,)(apple|banana|mango)(?!.*?,$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cN8yZ7/1)

Answer (score 0):

If your engine supports ***lookbehinds*** then I suggest using this:

```
^(?<!,)((apple|banana|mango),?)+(?<!,)$
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tR6zB8/2)

If it doesn't you can achieve it with using ***lookaheads***:

```
^(?=[,]*?)(?!.*,$)((apple|banana|mango),?)+$
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/kX6wJ1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Edit - with the comma delimiter issue, you can validate the whole string at once to insure
there is not a dangling comma at either the beginning, middle nor end like this -

```
 # ^[^,]+(?:,[^,]+)*$

 ^ 
 [^,]+ 
 (?: , [^,]+ )*
 $
```

The comma delimiter issue aside, the least common denominator is something like this

```
 # ^(?si)[a-z].*(?<=[a-z])$

 ^                 # BOS
 (?si)             # Modifiers s = Dot-All, i = Case Insensitive
 [a-z]             # single required char, a-z case insensitive
 .*                # optional many any chars
 (?<= [a-z] )      # before the end, single char a-z case insensitive
 $                 # EOS
```